# when i have running the impdp commands

Tags: oracle, impdp

```
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "/nav_db_dir/cmODF_odf_nav_db/ashsahu/gabq418/RDF_ANT_181G0/RDF_WTA_181G0_ANT.dmp" for read
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3
```

Below is my command I have created directory DirectoryName Path directoryObject /import/datatest

```
impdp username/password@sid table_exists_action=REPLACE tables=SCHMEA.TABLE1,SCHMEA.TABLE2, SCHMEA.TABLE3, SCHMEA.TABLE4, SCHMEA.TABLE5 DIRECTORY=directoryObject remap_schema=SCHMEA:username remap_tablespace=SCHMEA_DA:username_DA dumpfile=file.dmp exclude=grant nologfile=y
```

And I have given the full access to this directory using `chmod 777 /import/datatest (rwxrwxrwx) –`

Comment: What's unclear about "*No such file or directory*"?

Answer (score 1):

You should have posted the whole `IMPDP` command.

I suspect that you misunderstood/misused the `DIRECTORY` parameter.

It is an Oracle object, created by `SYS`, and is only (generally speaking) a "pointer" to a physical directory on the database server's hard disk. After it is created, `SYS` should give you (i.e. the user which is running the IMPDP command) `read` (and, possibly, `write`) privileges on that directory.

Then you'd use it as

```
impdp scott/tiger@orcl directory=IMP_DIR dumpfile=mydump.dmp logfile=imp.log
      -----                      -------
      is granted READ privilege  |
                                 directory object
```

Finally, `mydump.dmp` (or whatever its name is) must reside in that directory on the server.

Comment: Below is my command
i have created directory 
DirectoryName      Path
directoryObject    /import/datatest

impdp username/password@sid table_exists_action=REPLACE tables=SCHMEA.TABLE1,SCHMEA.TABLE2, SCHMEA.TABLE3, SCHMEA.TABLE4, SCHMEA.TABLE5 DIRECTORY=directoryObject remap_schema=SCHMEA:username remap_tablespace=SCHMEA_DA:username_DA dumpfile=file.dmp exclude=grant nologfile=y;

even i have given the full access to this directory using chmod 777  /import/datatest (rwxrwxrwx)

Comment: Sorry, this is difficult to read. You'd rather post it - formatted - while editing the original message you posted half a day ago.

Comment: impdp username/password@sid table_exists_action=REPLACE tables=SCHMEA.TABLE1,SCHMEA.TABLE2, SCHMEA.TABLE3, SCHMEA.TABLE4, SCHMEA.TABLE5 DIRECTORY=directoryObject remap_schema=SCHMEA:username remap_tablespace=SCHMEA_DA:username_DA dumpfile=file.dmp exclude=grant nologfile=y;

Comment: i have created directory 



DirectoryName      Path
directoryObject    /import/datatest

Comment: even i have given the full access to this directory using chmod 777  /import/datatest

Comment: i can see my directory using below query 
select * from dba_directories ;

Comment: It is not about operating system privileges, but database level ones. SYS should `grant read, write on directory directoryName to username`

Comment: i am running this command on oracle client and the path is also on linux machine where oracle client mounted

Comment: i can see db  Privilege list EXECUTE, READ, READ, READ, READ, WRITE, WRITE, WRITE, WRITE for this directory

Comment: Make sure also that the username that Oracle is running as, let's say "oracle", has access to both the "/import" directory, and the "/import/datatest" directory. Make sure that the user can "cd" into /import/datatest

Comment: Also you said that the path is on the Linux machine where the client is. It should be on the machine that the database is running on, that's where the dump file needs to be.

Comment: Hi Adam ,i have given  the access permission for oracle user like chown oracle:oracle /import/datatest  , Still no success for this

Comment: Hi Adam, no more thing , i am using the oracle client which is on different linux server and i tried to give the full permission for oracle user then it was showing chown: invalid user:oracle :oracle

Comment: ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation                                                                                                                                     Now this issue i am facing , i have given full access permission

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @Littlefoot said

Example:

```
Create directory datapump as '/import/datatest';
Grant read,write on directory datapump to scott;
```

And then the dump file should reside @ /import/datatest

Make sure also that the username that Oracle is running as, let's say "oracle", has access to both the "/import" directory, and the "/import/datatest" directory. Make sure that the user can "cd" into /import/datatest